# Combine Multiple CSV into One R Data

Tags: r, csv

I have 1 folder consists of more than 100 csv files, each has different column names, and different file names. The example would be as below:

```
[1] "Data/Yahoo_2014.csv"   "Data/Yahoo_2015.csv"  
[3] "Data/Yahoo_2016.csv"   "Data/Yahoo_2017.csv"  
[5] "Data/Yahoo_2018.csv"   "Data/Yahoo_2019.csv"  
[7] "Data/Yahoo_2020.csv"   "Data/Google_2014.csv"
[9] "Data/Google_2015.csv"  "Data/Google_2016.csv"

etc
```

Each csv has different column names. Example
for Yahoo Data

```
Date Yahoo
```

for Google

```
Date Google
```

The only thing that is similar is the first column (Date). I want to merge all of this data into one csv file in R so that I can proceed to analyze it. The result should be as below:

```
Date Yahoo Google
1   2014-01-05  75  50
2   2014-01-12  84  6
3   2014-01-19  81  3
4   2014-01-26  82  35
```

I already looked at other questions in StackOverflow but found nothing similar. I came up with this solution but it won't work because they have different column names.

```
data <- read.csv(paste0("Data/","Yahoo_2014.csv"),
                       skip=2, 
                       na.strings="<1")

allFileNames <- list.files("Data")
All <- data.frame(matrix(, nrow=0, ncol=3))
names(All) <- c("Date","Yahoo","Google")
for (filename in allFileNames) {
  fullFilename <- paste0("Data/",filename)
  Data <- read.csv(fullFilename,
                         skip=2, 
                         na.strings="<1")
  names(trendsData) <- c("Date","Yahoo","Google")
  All <- rbind(All,Data)
}
```

Comment: (1) Based on [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) chapter 2 (growing objects), don't iteratively call `rbind(All,Data)`, it scales horribly. (2) In the dupe question, look in the answer for *"Combining a list of data frames into a single data frame"*, it is relevant to you.

Comment: already make a list and do as your 2nd suggestions said :  
`my_files <- list.files(path = 'Data', pattern = "csv$", full.names = FALSE)
big_data = dplyr::bind_cols(my_files)` 

but still there's error message `Error: Argument 1 must have names`

Comment: You missed the step where you actually *read in the data*, perhaps with `alldat <- lapply(my_files, read.csv, skip=2, na.strings="<1")`.

Comment: `allFileNames <- list.files(path = 'Data', pattern = "csv$", full.names = FALSE)
for (filename in allFileNames) {
  fullFilename <- paste0("Data/",filename)
  allFileNames <- read.csv(fullFilename,
                         skip=2, 
                         na.strings="<1")
}
big_data = dplyr::bind_cols(allFileNames)
`
use this but the result is not what i expected. I need to have 3 columns, including Date, Yahoo, Google but with this code I only got 2, Date and Data (Yahoo and Google merged into one column)

Comment: I suggest you `split` your files into `Google` and `Yahoo`, read them into separate frames, then figure out if and how you can `merge` them together based on `Date`.

Comment: yes that's one way to do it. But I have 15 different file names so I guess it's not effective to do so

Comment: `split(allFileNames, grepl("Google", allFileNames))`